# Trying to start the server using npm start

Tags: reactjs, installation

Following is the package.json file which is present in my local.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "2.1.8",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is the audit file that got created upon trying npm start.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\mouni/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mouni\package.json'
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\mouni
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
9 verbose node v12.16.3
10 verbose npm  v6.14.4
11 error code ENOENT
12 error syscall open
13 error path C:\Users\mouni\package.json
14 error errno -4058
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mouni\package.json'
16 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
17 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Please help me with this I am trying something new.

following is the content I get upon giving the npm start.

```
C:\Users\mouni>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mouni\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mouni\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mouni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-11T23_12_55_465Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to ensure that the environmental variable PATH is set with the following elements or not .After that everything worked well.

List :-
node.js,
npm

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOiNX.png)